# PHP - Efficiently search array by one of two or more parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I had a simple array:

```
$arr = [
    'id1' => 'lotsOfData1',
    'id2' => 'lotsOfData2',
    'id3' => 'lotsOfData3',
];
```

Searching this array was as easy as `$arr[$myId]`;

What if I want to be able to find lotsOfData by means other than id? Maybe I have a case like this: `id - name - email - lotsOfData`. I assume each value for id, name, and email is unique. I have several ideas:

regex or explode:

```
$arr = [
    'id1&name lastname&email1' => 'lotsOfData1',
    'id2&nameonly&email2' => 'lotsOfData2',
    'id3&&email3' => 'lotsOfData3', // guy 3 is nameless
];
```

Problems - finding a char to explode that will never appear in any of the search values, and if using regex then regex is slow. A bit clumsy to later find the full key value by array position.

array_column:

```
$arr = [
    0 => ['id' => 'id1', 'name' => 'name lastname', 'email1' => 'email', 'data' => 'lotsOfData'],
    0 => ['id' => 'id2', 'name' => 'namey', 'email' => 'email2', 'data' => 'lotsOfData'],
    //etc
];
```

And:

```
return $arr[array_search($myId, array_column($arr, 'id'))]['data']; //by id

return $arr[array_search($myEmail, array_column($arr, 'email'))]['data']; //by email
```

I like this solution better, but I'm not a huge fan of the array structure.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: So you're serach the second example of `$arr` and searching for what the id?

Comment: "I like this solution better, but I'm not a huge fan of the array structure." It's a way cleaner structure than the regex structure you proposed above it.

Comment: `$arr[array_search(array_column($arr, 'id'))]['data']`  Woops, you already have this.  This is what I would do.  There is no `fan of the array structure` based on the search.  That is how you access arrays.

Comment: I would not be exploding, you could do something with `preg_grep($regx, array_keys($arr))` maybe, reference  [preg_grep](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

Answer (score 2):

For this array, I wouldn't do explode.

```
$arr = [
    'id1&name lastname&email1' => 'lotsOfData1',
    'id2&nameonly&email2' => 'lotsOfData2',
    'id3&&email3' => 'lotsOfData3', // guy 3 is nameless
];
```

Instead

```
 $res = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(preg_grep('/^id3/', array_keys($arr))));

 print_r($res);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [id3&&email3] => lotsOfData3
)
```

Try it [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d1a7b99c15140a4b37095b8b8b07735eab1b51c)

It's pretty wild, but it works.  And, and it only uses 4 functions calls.. :-p

I actually use something like this for an event system, where the events can be listened to using a Regex, it works good.

Comment: Thank you, it is always interesting to read your replies. So you would go with regex over array columns?

Comment: I would go with what made sense using the array structure you have.  They are different.  But ignoring that array column is faster.  But it also doesn't have fuzzy searching like a Regx.  So it all depends. You already had the other, so I just added this one.  No preference, whichever suits the needs.  The example I mentioned I needed fuzzy searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple associative arrays that contain the rows with different keys:

```
$arr_by_id = [];
$arr_by_name = [];
$arr_by_email = [];
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $arr_by_id[$row['id']] = $row;
    $arr_by_name[$row['name'] = $row;
    $arr_by_email[$row['email']] = $row;
}
```

Now if you want to look someone up by email, you do:

```
$x = $arr_by_email['data'];
```

You can use references if you want to be able to modify the row data from any of the associative arrays.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, and using references can definitely make it easy. Is there any major downside to this? I imagine that removing or rearranging members could be a little more tedious than usual, but nothing impossible.

Comment: Yeah, if you add a new row to `$arr` you also need to update all the keyed arrays. You can create a function for this.

Comment: Wrapping it in a class might be useful, too.